# Change z-index in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working on a project I inherited involving JS which I'm new to. I need to change the z-index of markers on a map and a few other objects on the page.

Is there a way to set the z-index for all my features (to 7) when they are imported? I tried z-index: 7; in .setHTML. Any other suggestions?

```
geojson.features.forEach(function(feature) {

    let type = feature.properties['type'];
    let symbol = icons[type];

    // create class names to use as tags for filtering
    let typeTag = typeTags[type];
    let title = feature.properties['title'];
    let impact = feature.properties['impact'];
    let impactTag = impactTags[impact];
    let sType = feature.properties['studyType'];
    let studyType = studyTypes[sType];
    let tooltipStudy = feature.properties['studyType'];
    let ttStudy = tooltipStudyTypes[tooltipStudy];
    let uniqueStudies = feature.properties['unique'];
    let uniqueStudy = unique[uniqueStudies]

    // replave hash marks with smart quotes
    let summary = feature.properties['summary'];
    summary = "\u201c" + summary + "\u201d";

    let url = feature.properties['link'];
    let citation1 = feature.properties['citation'];
    let clipCitation = citation1.split("),")[0];
    console.log(clipCitation)
    let substr = "pdf";

    if (url.indexOf(substr) !== -1) {
        clipCitation = clipCitation + " [pdf]";
    }

    // create a HTML element for each feature
    var el = document.createElement('div');
    el.className = "marker" + " " + typeTag + " " + impactTag;
    el.innerHTML = '<i class="' + symbol + '"></i>';

    // make a marker for each feature and add to the map
    new mapboxgl.Marker(el)
    .setLngLat(feature.geometry.coordinates)
    .setPopup(new mapboxgl.Popup({ offset: 10, closeButton: false }) // add popups
    .setHTML('<h4 style="padding-bottom: 4px; border-bottom: 2px solid ' + colors[impactTag] + ';">' + feature.properties['title'] + '</h4><ul class="list-group list-tooltip"><li>Area of study: ' + feature.properties['location'] + '</li><li><div style="display:inline-block" class=' + impactTag + '>' + popupIcon[type] + "</div>"  
    + impactTag + " " + 'that climate change increases the risk of wildfires.</li></ul><p class="summary">' 
    + summary + '</p><p class="citation"><a href="'
    + url + '" target="_blank">' + clipCitation + "),</a><span class='citation2'> " + feature.properties['journal'] + '</span></p>'))
    .addTo(map);


});
```

Comment: `z-index` is a CSS property, if you want to access it or change it with JS you would need `element.style.zIndex = "7"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To change any CSS styles with JavaScript use `document.getElementById("item").style.XXX = "value";`, change `XXX` with the thing you want to change, in your case `z-index`:

```
 document.getElementById("item").style.zIndex = "7";
```

you can do the same thing with jQuery with more simple way :

```
$("#item").css("z-index","7");
```